# "addq" overflowing at max 32-bit signed integer

Tags: assembly, y86

I'm attempting to write a simple compiler for a calculator. However, all of my assembly instructions (add, subtract, and multiply) keep overflowing and underflowing at 2,147,483,647 and −2,147,483,648 respectively, rather than the maximum 64-bit signed values. I can't figure out why this is happening and its really frustrating, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the assembly code generated in case this helps:

```
.globl compute
compute:
movq   $2147483646, %rcx
pushq  %rcx
movq   $2147483646, %rcx
pushq  %rcx
popq   %rcx
popq   %r8
addq   %rcx, %r8
pushq  %r8
popq   %rax
retq
```

However, this returns the value -4, rather than 4,294,967,292 as I expected it would :(.
(I know it's not optimized at the moment, I hope to improve on that later after I figure out this issue. Thanks!)

Comment: You are printing the result wrong, not shown in the question.

Comment: It works fine for me, when compiled against this main .cpp file: `extern "C" long compute(); \\ #include <iostream> \\ int main() { std::cout << "compute() returns " << compute() << '\n'; return 0; }`

Comment: I took a look at the test I was using and you guys were right! Thanks so much :)